How to convert high cardinality key to low cardinality key in cassandra observability springboot?
I'm using springboot cassandra observability to push cassandra metrices to prometheus. But in prometheus endpoint, able to see only low cardinality keys. Followed this link
Unable to fetch high cardinality keys.So, I'm trying to convert high cardinality key db.statement of cassandra into low cardinality and push to prometheus using springboot observability.
Can anyone please provide some suggestions or example code to convert high to low cardinality in springboot cassandra observability?
